# IntelliJ - Count number of words in a text selection

Tags: intellij-idea, latex

IntelliJ shows the number of characters and linebreak at the right bottom corner of the screen when we select a text. I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to count number of words in a text selection.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [TeXiFy IDEA plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9473-texify-idea) offers great latex support and has a word count function included:

[image]

This word count function only counts "real" words and ignores commands. Hence, it's only able to work wit `tex` files.

See this screenshot for the result:
[image]

Comment: Oh wow, I was looking for a separate plugin when what I needed was included in TeXiFy all along. Talk about missing the forest for the trees!

Answer (score 4):

It looks like there's no built-in way to do this, but we can leverage `External Tools` to accomplish this.

I'm using IntelliJ on Linux, so wrote a bash script like the below using `wc`

```
$ cat wordCounter.sh
#!/bin/bash
echo -e "$1" | wc -w

$ chmod +x wordCounter.sh #make it executable
```

Then, in IDE navigate to `File -> Settings -> External Tools -> (Click on + to add a new tool)`

`External Tool` details:

- Name: word counter
- Program: `/path/to/wordCounter.sh`
- Arguments: `"$SelectedText$"`
- Working Directory: `$ProjectFileDir$`

Click on `Ok -> Apply`. Now to count words, select the text, then right click and select `External Tools -> word counter`

The selected text will be passed to the script, and will output the total number of words.

Answer (score 1):

@Junaid's answer works well if you don't have any quotes in the highlighted text, which messes up the count in certain circumstances. If you're OK with counting all the words in the WHOLE FILE an alternative using the same basic approach to follow the same process with the following alterations:

```
$ cat wordCounter.sh
#!/bin/bash
wc -l "$1"
```

This feeds the file itself directly into wc. Then in the External Tools section, use this for the Arguments field: "$FilePath$" (including the quotes).

Answer (score 1):

Since having quotes inside a text would make it look (for bash) as a list of parameters, I simple concatenated all the params with `$@`, which would remove the quotes and not impact the word count.

```
$ cat wordcount.sh
#!/bin/bash
wc -w <<THE_TEXT
$@
THE_TEXT
```

In PHPStorm (so I assume works the same in any JetBrains IDE) I defined the External Tool as follows:

Program: `/path/to/wordcount.sh`
Arguments: `"$SelectedText$"`
Working directory: `$ProjectFileDir$`

I would like for JetBrains to add a few simple macros to the arguments box, like a string-replace or multi-line to make it simpler, but this works.